# In Backbone : Show cursor:pointer on anchor tag that does not have href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, backbone.js

In Backbone.Js in a BackboneView I am having an anchor tag like below

`<a class="btn-export" style="cursor: pointer">Export</a>`

and that `btn-export` class is created to trigger the click event on the anchor tag.

`events: {'click .btn-export': 'exportInfo'}`

I want to show cursor pointer to this but I don't want to add inline style.

Is it possible to show it using pseudo class or any other possible way.

Comment: And why not use just css `.btn-export { cursor: pointer; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Each BackboneView consist of `$el` cached jquery object. Using $el is same accessing the DOM of the window using jquery but restricted to the view's elements present in the DOM. You can find more about the el property over [here](https://backbonejs.org/#View-el).
So after the view is rendered you can do following:

```js
// when mouse enters the anchor tag
<ViewInstance>.$el.find(".btn-export").hover(function(){
  <View>.$el.find(".btn-export").css("cursor", "pointer");
}, 
function(){
  <ViewInstance>.$el.find(".btn-export").css("cursor", "default");
});
```

In case of jquery do it as:

```js
$("btn-export").hover(function1, function2);
```

**OR**

You define all your styles in a separate css files say `style.css`. And declare your class as:

```css
.btn-export:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

FYI, you need to include this css file in your HTML file. Hope you know that.